# How can I create a chicken substitute?

Tags: vegetarian, vegan, substitutions

How can I create a homemade product with that has the texture, flavor, and cooking properties of chicken, but is vegetarian (or vegan)?

I'm inspired by the Lightlife, the [Sipz](http://www.sipz.com/) orange "chicken", and [Veggie Grill](http://www.veggiegrill.com/) "burgers" but am looking for something more flexible that I can make myself.

I'm not looking for a specific recipe, but rather general techniques and ingredients to use as a starting point.

Comment: As far as I can see, you need a factory to get the texture right.

Answer (score 6):

[Seitan (aka. wheat gluten/vital wheat gluten/wheat meat/fu*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seitan) can be used to make chik'n nugget type chicken, but not as in breast or thigh, etc. Recipes abound on the internets.

- The gist of using it involves bringing together compositional ingredients (basically the gluten) and flavoring, mixing to develop it into a rubbery mass, forming it into and using as a dough (i.e. making chik'n nugget cutouts).

*There are differences between these, but they are all basically the same beast.

Comment: Seitan is a pretty good sub for chicken; works better than tofu for most things (anything where chicken is cut up into pieces; stirfry, tacos, chick'n 'n' dumplin' soup, etc.)

Comment: @TJ Ellis how well does it hold up in brothy stuff like as you would have with chicken and dumplings? I've only had it dry (dressed/sauced after), typically breaded.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers; looking forward to trying this out

Comment: it holds up pretty well in brothy stuff! it's often made by boiling the dough in a broth for a couple hours, in fact, and continues to hold up fairly well in applications after that too.

Comment: specifically, in my experience, it works great for chicken and dumplings!

Answer (score 6):

There are a few recipes on the Vegan Dad blog for veggie chicken from scratch:

- [Chick'n Burgers](http://vegandad.blogspot.com/2008/03/chickn-burgers.html) (but read the comments also)
- [Chick'n Nuggets](http://vegandad.blogspot.com/2008/06/chickenless-nuggets.html)

Chicken-flavored vegetarian broth is usually a key ingredient. You can find a lot of them on Amazon, and sometimes in health food stores. I usually use [Edward and Son's Not Chick'n bouillon](http://amzn.com/B00113ZTVK) cubes, just because they sell them in a store on my block.

There's also a company called [eco-cuisine](http://www.eco-cuisine.com/index.html) that sells mixes, but I haven't tried them.

For other pre-made options [May Wah](http://www.vegieworld.com/) in NYC supplies meat substitutes to a ton of vegan restaurants, and Gardein has some great veggie [chick'n scallopini cutlets](http://www.gardein.com/products.php?t=frozen&p=5) you can use for a lot of recipes.

Comment: no problem. btw - these are awesome and not commonly known: http://www.vegieworld.com/cart/product_pages.asp?id=540 - At Red Bamboo in NYC they deep fry them and add buffalo bbq sauce for an amazing wing substitute, but I pan fry them at home.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Chinese dry tofu (Dòu gān) as a starting point. It is nutritionally good and has a 'meatlike' texture.

http://www.thetofuboutique.com/?p=454&page=4

Answer (score 1):

For stewing, I love Green Jackfruit -canned or frozen. Fooled me entirely in a Malaysian curry. Needs long gentle simmering in flavorful broth/sauce. Flakes fleshily when forked.

Beancurd sticks are those shrivelled yellow plastic batons in cellaphane packs that cook up first rubbery then slowly disintegrating to desired tenderness. Forgot it once in a hotpot for 2 hrs and it was chicken soup!

Answer (score 1):

I know someone had already mentioned Chick'n nuggets, but you could also try the Quorn brand "chicken" items. They have a very similar texture to chicken. But if you are looking for a veggie burger, then i found this great recipe for Black Bean cakes.
http://allrecipes.com/recipe/spicy-black-bean-cakes/detail.aspx and they are pretty easy and delicious too!

Answer (score 1):

For 'chicken' strips I often use tofu that has been pressed for a really long time so it has less of a squishy texture, then roll it in flour paprika and salt and flash fry it until it's golden brown and crispy on the outside.